# How to get value from a field key (Ninja Forms)

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

Having a try with Ninja Forms, I’m actually able to get value from a `field ID` using `$form_data` array variable.

```
function my_ninja_function( $form_data ) {

$my_field_id = 1;
$my_value_from_field_id = $form_data['fields'][$my_field_id]['value'];

echo $my_value_from_field_id;
// output value is possible

}
```

And now trying to get value from a field key, without success...

```
$my_field_key = 'my_key';
$my_value_from_field_key = $form_data['fields'][$my_field_key]['value'];

echo $my_value_from_field_key;
// output value is not possible
```

Answer (score 0):

with a little more effort...

```
$form_fields = $form_data['fields'];

foreach( $form_fields as $field ){
    $field_value       = $field['value'];
    $field_key         = $field['key'];
    $data[$field_key]  = $field_value;
};

$my_value_from_key = $data['my_key'];

echo $my_value_from_key;
// output is possible
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

By value I'm assuming you mean the field's label. You can get a field's label from the field's settings like this:

```
$form_id = 1;
$form_fields = Ninja_Forms()->form($form_id)->get_fields();

foreach( $form_fields as $field ) { 
     $model = $field->get_settings();
     $label = $model['label'];
}
```

if you really do mean value, then perhaps you are referring to a form submission's field value. You can get those like this:

```
$sub_id = 1; // Need to know the submission's ID
$sub = Ninja_Forms()->form()->sub($sub_id)->get();
$form_id = 1;
$form_fields = Ninja_Forms()->form($form_id)->get_fields();
    
foreach( $form_fields as $field ) { 
     $model = $field->get_settings();
     $value = $sub->get_field_value($model['key']); // User submitted value
}
```

Note that NinjaForms has added field keys in version 3 after I made the suggestion, as previous versions had no unique field identifier which made exporting/importing fields and forms very problematic.